# Need some SQLite QuicK Help Android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

so I have:

```
public Cursor fetchnondownloaded(){
    return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String [] {KEY_TITLE, KEY_URL}, "downloaded = 0", null, null, null, null, "1");
}
```

and I was wondering how do I get those two strings KEY_TITLE and KEY_URL out of that query.

Comment: Could you clarify? Are you saying the query you currently have does not work and if so, what happens.

Answer (score 3):

For title is something like that:

```
int titleCol = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_TITLE);
String title = cursor.getString(titleCol);
```

I recommend notepad tutorial:

http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/notepad/index.html